# PG: ERROR: relation "admin_users" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am currently getting the following error when I run `heroku logs`, after trying to login to the admin/login part of my production URL:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation “admin_users"  does not exist
```

I have tried followed this thread :https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/753, i.e. specifically the following suggested steps (suggested to be performed on a "new install" which I am unclear  what that means!)

1. rails g active_admin:devise
2. rails g active_admin:install
3. (If install fails because of #2414, remove duplicate ActiveAdmin.routes(self) from routes file, then run rails g active_admin:assets)
   remove add_devise_to_admin_users migration file
4. rake db:migrate

   I have done the above steps w/o adhering to the "new install" portion but am still getting the same error.

Here is the copy of my `database.yml` file:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile  
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  password:

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myapp_production
  username: 
  password: 
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Here is the copy of my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.1.1"

gem 'rails', '4.0.4'



gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'


gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'


gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end


gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Answer (score 3):

After you push your code to Heroku via `git`, switch to your project root and run:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

This will run `rake db:migrate` on your production server.

Comment: when I run `heroku run rake db:create` I get this error: `FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.`

Comment: @Thalatta My mistake.  You can't run `db:create` or `db:drop` on Heroku.  Did `db:migrate` create the right tables for you?

Comment: it is unclear. How can I see what tables are created? It just displays: 1Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2915`

Comment: @Thalatta You can try `$ heroku pg:psql DATABASE` then type `\dt`.  Type `\q` to quit.

Comment: Sorry hitting you with issues. But when I type `heroku pg:psql DATABASE` I get: `---> Connecting to HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL (DATABASE_URL)
sh: psql: command not found` I think may PostGreSQL is not in my path?

Comment: @Thalatta You may have problems with your local copy of PostgreSQL in that case.  Can you run `psql` and/or `rails db` locally?

Comment: Add PostgreSQL to your path.  This is most likely the heart of all your problems.  Restart your terminal after you do it to make sure you can `whereis psql` successfully.

Comment: I personally use `~/.bash_profile`.  Add `PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH; export PATH;` to the end of the file.

Comment: It looks like `heroku run rake db:migrate` did not create the right tables. When I run `heroku pg:psql DATABASE` and then `\dt admin_users` It says there `No matching relations found`